# In SSMS I need to split more than one column, keeping the data in order, based on comma separation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have data from customer source that I need to split based on commas within two strings.  The two strings are linked, i.e. position 1 in Column A should link to position 1 in Column B, etc.  What I have so far, taken from a similar question and modified, is the following, but it is not returning results before the first comma, and is returning only one set of results after.  I have some rows with up to around 50 comma separations in the field...

Note that STRING_SPLIT Won't work here as I need the categories in order to match the other field being split...

```
;WITH tmp ([Product Id],
        [Product Reference],
        [Active],
        [Name],
        [Price (exc# VAT)],
        DataItem1,
        [Categories Ids],
        DataItem2,
        [Categories Names],
        [Images]) AS
(
    SELECT
        [Product Id],
        [Product Reference],
        [Active],
        [Name],
        [Price (exc# VAT)],
        LEFT([Categories Ids], CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Ids] + ',') - 1),
        STUFF([Categories Ids], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Ids] + ','), ''),
        LEFT([Categories Names], CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Names] + ',') - 1),
        STUFF([Categories Names], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Names] + ','), ''),
        Images
    FROM customerdata..products
    UNION all

    SELECT
        [Product Id],
        [Product Reference],
        [Active],
        [Name],
        [Price (exc# VAT)],
        LEFT([Categories Ids], CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Ids] + ',') - 1),
        STUFF([Categories Ids], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Ids] + ','), ''),
        LEFT([Categories Names], CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Names] + ',') - 1),
        STUFF([Categories Names], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [Categories Names] + ','), ''),
        Images
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        [Categories Ids] > ''
        AND [Categories Names] > ''
)

SELECT
   [Product Id] AS PROD_ID,
        [Product Reference] AS PROD_REF,
        [Active],
        [Name],
        [Price (exc# VAT)] AS PRICE,
        [Categories Ids] AS CAT_NO,
        [Categories Names] AS CAT_NAME,
        [Images]
FROM tmp
ORDER BY PROD_REF
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

EDIT:  The query above is from a similar question elsewhere, I'm honestly not sure if it will be close to what I required, I simply tried this and... failed!

Sample data as requested:

[image: Sample 1]

Desired Output splits the Category ID and Category Names columns down on to new rows:

[image: Output]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  And, it is not really clear what that query has to do with the question right above it.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: And please share output data.

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Comment: So it is the category Id and Category Name columns that need separating and filtering down along with the relevant part references, etc.  for each item.  Some category columns can contain 50+ categories, separated by commas.  I hope this makes sense.  The example provided just shows two categories.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the comma-seperated strings into valid JSON arrays and use OPENJSON, which outputs the ordinal position of array members as a seperate column.  EG

```
select * 
from openjson('[10,20,30,40]')
```

outputs

```
key       value         type
--------- ------------- ----
0         10            2
1         20            2
2         30            2
3         40            2
```

Then you can use the position to join the corresponding IDs and Names.

Comment: Thank you but in all honesty, I don't know how to transform into a JSON array

Comment: Paste sample data (not pictures of sample data) in your question.